# How can we find transfer function of this n/w

Tags: circuit-analysis, control-system, transfer-function

How can we find the transfer function $$\frac{E_0(s)}{E_1(s)}$$ of this RC network

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff6m8q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the capacitor C with an impedance of value \$Z_c = 1/(Cs)\$ and apply voltage division rule.

ie, 
$$ E_0(s) = E_1(s) \times \frac{Z_c}{R+Z_c}$$

or, 
$$\frac{E_0(s)}{E_1(s)} = \frac{Z_c}{Z_c+R}$$

Answer (score 2):

With resistor potential dividers like this: -

[image]

It's exactly the same for any impedance. On your circuit, the impedance at the bottom is \$\dfrac{1}{s\cdot C}\$ where s is \$2\cdot\pi\cdot f\$.

Therefore the transfer function is: -

\$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{s\cdot C}}{{\dfrac{1}{s\cdot C} + R}}\$ and this reduces to: -

\$\dfrac{1}{1+s\cdot C\cdot R}\$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{E0(s)}{E1(s)}=\frac{\frac{1}{s \cdot C}}{R+\frac{1}{s \cdot C}} = \frac{1}{1+s \cdot C \cdot R}$$